# Performance MPI and MPI+OpenMP. Speedup and efficiency

Tags: performance, mpi, openmp

The program I used to measure performance has an implementation in MPI and one with OpenMP+MPI where 2 threads and 4 threads are used to parallelize the loop present in the program. The program performs image convolution. The dimensions of the images supplied as input and on which the measurements were made are: 1920x2520, 3840x5040 and 5760x7560. The system on which the program was run has four computational nodes, each node has two processors with 8 cores, for a total of 16 cores per node. There are not many threads per processor as I don't know the processor model, I only know that they are 3.4 GHz Xeons. The graphs shown are related to speedup and efficiency.

The two graphs below are for running the MPI version on 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, and 64 processors. It can be seen that the speedup grows linearly as the processors grow, even if it deviates a lot from the ideal speedup. Instead the efficiency except for 2 and 4 processors, drops to the value 0.6 and remains constant.

[image]

The following graphs are related to the execution of the OpenMP+MPI version with 2(1), 4(2), 8(4), 16(8), 24(12), 32(16), 48(24), 64 (32), 96(48) and 128(64) threads, in brackets are the processors used from the command line or -np 1, 2, 4 etc. As it is possible to notice up to 64 threads the speedup relative to the 3840x5040 and 5760x7560 images is superlinear then gradually decreases. I think this decrease is due to the fact that the threads available are fewer than those requested and consequently the overhead for communication and thread synchronization increases considerably and this leads to a decrease in the speedup. Instead, for the 1920x2520 image, the speedup is superlinear up to 16 threads and then drops below the ideal value, i.e. equal to n.

[image]

Latest graphs are running OpenMP+MPI version with 4(1), 8(2), 16(4), 32(8), 48(12), 64(16), 96(24), 128( 32), 192(48) and 256(64) threads, in brackets are the processors used from the command line or -np 1, 2, 4 etc. We have that up to 64 threads the speedup relative to the 3840x5040 and 5760x7560 images is superlinear then gradually decreases, always due to the fact that the threads available are fewer than those requested. Same speech above for the 1920x2520 image.
[image]

Analyzing the graphs the best solution is the one with 4 threads to run the program as there are 64 (-np 16) threads with an execution time less than the MPI version of about 50% lower. Or am I wrong? Do you have any tips on how to analyze these speedup and efficiency graphs? Can you give me some other more detailed consideration? Thank you.

Comment: If you have the cluster for yourself alone, and have a single task to run, you will look for the maximum speedup. If the cluster is shared between several users, or if you have many tasks to run, you will look for some compromise between speed-up and efficiency.

Comment: Can you try with 8 MPI process and 8 OMP threads (-np 8 OMP_THREADS 8)? In this scenario each socket has an MPI process and in every socket there will be 8 OMP threads. Thereby completely utilising the cores and also accounting for the NUMA performance aspect.

Comment: By the way, how do define the "efficiency" here ?

Comment: @PierU, I have the cluster just for me for a university exam, to run this program exclusively. I defined the efficiency as `speedUp/n`

Comment: @j23, with -np 8 and 8 threads I have the same times with -np 16 and 4 threads

Comment: Efficiencies > 1 are not common...

Comment: @PierU, If I have a speed up greater than the number of processors (superlinear speed up), shouldn't I also have the efficiency greater than 1?

Comment: You're correct. I just say that it's not common. If it's an exam you could be asked to give an explanation. It can happen when the implementation is not the best possible one for a sequential execution.

Comment: @PierU, Or also because the number of cache misses of the hybrid version is 50/60% lower than the MPI version. So there are fewer accesses to primary memory.

Comment: Yes, but it often means that the sequential code could be reorganised to minimize the cache misses

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is right. Only thing I would try extra in this scenario is I will use number of `MPI processes = number of sockets` and number of `OMP threads = cores per socket`. This will then account for [performance overhead](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-webinar-vanderPas-20210318.pdf) caused by NUMA in OpenMP.

You can get your cpu architecture info by using the command `lscpu`. Using that you will get information about NUMA, caches etc which can be utilised to understand the benchmarking result.

My suggestion is to get the cpu architecture and calculate the [roofline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model) for your code and then revisit the same benchmarking result.

NB: Speedup might not always be the correct way to look into the code. It showcases the improvement made by running the code parallelely. Meaning, if you have an optimised code, it might give better performance than an unoptimised code with parallelisation.

So, you could use tools like intel advisor to see how your sequential code behaves and compares with the roofline. Also when you start looking into the code don't forget to check for chances of false sharing (which can happen with OMP a lot :)).

Comment: I don't have to go into much detail, the exam involves optimizing some MPI code in a hybrid version, running it to measure execution times and determine speed up and efficiency. Next I have to comment on the graphs.

Comment: I ran the lscpu command: Thread(s) for core: 2, Core(s) for socket: 8, Socket(s): 2 and NUMA node(s): 2.